# Why does my C++ recursive descent parser only work for a few computers?

Tags: c++, windows-xp, codeblocks

For some reason, my program doesn't seem to work on my computer which uses Code Blocks 12.11 or my professor's computer which uses VMware, but it runs perfectly well on two of classmates' computer who use Visual C++ 2012. Since my computer runs on Windows XP, I can't use Visual C++ 2012 or even 2010 so I have to work with Code Blocks. My program is designed to read a list of strings from a file and check if those strings are in the BNF grammar.

No error is ever printed. The program compiles just fine but it has no output when ran on my or my professor's computer.

EDIT: The expected output should be for it to ask for the name of text file to read through it. Then, for each string in the file the program should output whether or not that string is in the language or not in the language. If the file does not exist, the program outputs "Operation failed." Instead of this, the program goes directly to "press any key to terminate" which is only suppose to show when a program has already finished running.

```
/* This is a recursive descent parser that uses the following productions. The
   '||' operator stands for concatenation. The '|' operator for alternatives.

P_statement -> P_Identifier = P_Expression | P_Expression
P_Expression -> P_Term + P_Expression | P_Term - P_Expression | P_Term
P_Term -> P_Factor * P_Term | P_Factor / P_Term | P_Factor
P_Factor -> P_Exponential ^ P_Factor | P_Exponential
P_Exponential -> P_Identifier | L | UI | UL | (P_statement)
P_Unary -> + | - | !
P_Identifier -> P_Character | P_Character||P_Identifier
P_Character -> a | b | ... | y | z
P_Number -> P_Digit | P_Digid||P_Number
P_Digit -> 0 | 1 | ... | 8 | 9
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios;
using std::ofstream;
using std::string;

// The functions that test whether the current string matches a particular
// production, hence the 'P_' prefix.
bool P_statement(void);
bool P_Expression(void);
bool P_Term(void);
bool P_Factor(void);
bool P_Exponential(void);
bool P_Unary(void);
bool P_Identifier(void);
bool P_Character(void);
bool P_Number(void);
bool P_Digit(void);

string s;

int main(){
   string mystr;
   cout << "What is your text file? ";
   cin >> mystr;
   ifstream input(mystr.c_str());

   if(input.is_open()){
      while(input.good()){
         getline(input, s);
         string C = s;
         if (P_statement() && s == ""){
            cout << "The string \"" << C << "\" is in the language." <<endl;
         }
         else {
            cout << "The string \"" << C << "\" is not in the language." <<endl;
         }
      }
      input.close();
   }
   else cout << "Operation failed" << endl;

   return 0;
}

bool P_statement(void) {

   if (P_Identifier()) {
      if (s[0] == '=') {
         s = s.substr(1);
         if (P_Expression()) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      s = s.substr(1);
   }
   if(P_Expression()){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Expression(void) {

  if (P_Term()) {
     if (s[0] == '+' || s[0] == '-') {
         s = s.substr(1);
         if (P_Expression()) {
            return true;
         }
     }
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}

bool P_Term(void) {

   if(P_Factor()){
      if (s[0]=='*' || s[0]=='/'){
         s = s.substr(1);
         if (P_Term()) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Factor(void){
   if (P_Exponential()) {
      if (s[0] == '^') {
         s = s.substr(1);
         if (P_Factor()) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Exponential(void){
   if(P_Identifier()){
      return true;
   }
   else if(P_Number()){
      return true;
   }
   else if(P_Unary()){
      if (P_Identifier()){
         return true;
      }
      else if(P_Number()){
         return true;
      }
   }
   else if (s[0] == '(') {
      s = s.substr(1);
      if (P_statement()) {
         if (s[0] == ')') {
            s = s.substr(1);
            return true;
         }
      }
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Unary(void){
   if (s[0] =='+' || s[0]=='-' || s[0]=='!'){
      s = s.substr(1);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Identifier(void) {
   if(P_Character()) {
      if(P_Identifier()){
         return true;
      }
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Character(void){
   if ('a' <= s[0] && s[0] <= 'z') {
      s = s.substr(1);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Number(void) {
   if(P_Digit()){
      if(P_Number()){
         return true;
      }
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}

bool P_Digit(void){
   if ('0' <= s[0] && s[0] <= '9') {
      s = s.substr(1);
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the expected output, and what do you get instead? Also, you have pasted a looot of code. Is there a subsection of the program that displays the same behaviour of not doing what you expect?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 has an XP compiler you can download for free. It might have been part of update 1.

Comment: Those function names and variable names are horrible.

Comment: You might start with changing `while(input.good())`. Don't loop on `.good()`. Instead, it should be `while(getline(input, s))`. This may change the behaviour. Like others have said, you have pasted a lot of code which you've done a pretty good job of obfuscating, and this makes it a lot harder to help.

Comment: you must follow good naming convention

Comment: Do you know you have a function and a string variable with the same name? (`C`)

Comment: This program is absolutely awful in several respects. I would never pass it in a code review.

Comment: Well, it seems to run just fine for me with gcc 4.7.2 on Fedora 18. And this is a recursive descent parser. I could pretty easily rename your functions to be actual logical names instead of what you currently have. Though what 'A' and 'L' are supposed to stand for are mysteries.

Comment: I don't know Code Blocks but surely this is a compiler/IDE issue not a programming issue. The program is running, more or less successfully, (I can see at least one bug) but Code Blocks is putting the output of the program somewhere you don't expect. Maybe you should try a one line program, `cout << "hello\n"`, see if you can get that working on Code Blocks. If you can't then you know the issue is your understanding of Code Blacks, not your understanding of C++ programming.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't a problem but with my compiler. Instead of wracking my brain over Code Blocks, I decided to go to Eclipse with CDT and everything worked fine. I thank you all for your help and constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2):

Your test functions have side effects, and you keep operating on a global string, `s`. You use array indexing into a string without checking how long it is. You are almost certainly getting undefined behaviour. This is likely the source of your variations between platforms.

The real problem, however, is that your code is unclear and it is not worth figuring out what it really does.

Update:

You say that "no error is printed" and "it has no output". That could be as simple as not flushing std::cout because of different standard library behaviour on Code Blocks. Just as a `<< endl` to the end of your first message and see if you get a flushed buffer. My other comments about undefined behaviour in your code still apply, but if you get no messages at all that is a likely first problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your program as written will accept this invalid statement and call it valid:

```
a=(a7-62)^2
```

You do not allow digits in identifiers, so this program is not a valid one according to your grammar. But your program will accept it.

Once you figure out why it does and fix the problem your program will likely have much more predictable behavior on different platforms.

Answer (score -3):

```
bool A(void);
bool E(void);
bool T(void);
bool F(void);
bool P(void);
bool U(void);
bool I(void);
bool C(void);
bool L(void);
bool D(void);
```

No.

Comment: Well, much as I want to vote this up, I can't bring myself to because it isn't really an answer to the question. It is very correct though. :-)

Comment: It's a shame the "Low Quality Posts" review task doesn't have a "suggest that the answerer improve their answer" button.